# Varnish x Apache CDN & HTTPs

Tags: apache, nginx, https, haproxy, varnish

I'm currently trying to setup a DYI CDN using Varnish, Nginx, & Apache.
This is the following setup I have planned.

The following assumes:

```
1. The Varnish Origin server is on the same server as the web server (Apache in this case)
2. You have 2 Varnish Cache Servers located in different countries, one in NA, & one in EU
```

Example of an NA client attempting to retrieve data:

```
NA Client --> Varnish Origin Server --> NA Varnish Cache Server --> If result NOT IN cache --> Return Apache Origin Server results --> Input request data into NA Varnish Cache Server
```

Example of an EU client attempting to retrieve data:

```
EU Client --> Varnish Origin Server --> EU Varnish Cache Server --> If result IN cache --> Return EU Varnish Cache results
```

Any suggestions and/or mistakes? Where would I insert Nginx/HAProxy in order to terminate SSL, since Varnish doesn't accept HTTPs?

Answer (score 0):

What you're suggesting is perfectly possible and has become an increasingly more popular use case for us at Varnish Software.

### Geolocation

First things first: I'm assuming all users, regardless of their location, will use the same hostname to connect to the CDN. Let's say the hostname is `www.example.com`.

US users should automatically connect to a Varnish edge node in the US, EU users should be directed to the EU.

This geographical targeting requires some sort of GeoDNS approach. If your DNS provider can do this for you, things will be a lot easier.

If not, I know for a fact that *AWS Route 53* does this. If you want to use open source technology, you can host the DNS zone yourself using https://github.com/abh/geodns/.

So if a US user does a DNS call on `www.example.com`, this should resolve to `us.example.com`. For EU users this will be `eu.example.com`.

### Topology

Your setup will connect from the a local Varnish server to a remote Varnish server. This seems like one hop too many. If the geolocation properly works, you'll directly end up on the Varnish server that is closest to your user.

We call these geolocated servers "edge nodes". They will connect back to the origin server(s) in case requested content is not available in cache.

It's up to you to decide if one origin Apache will do, or if you want to duplicate your Apache servers in the different geographical regions.

### SSL/TLS

My advice in terms of SSL/TLS termination: Use [Hitch](http://hitch-tls.org/). It's a dedicated TLS Proxy that was developed by Varnish, to use with Varnish. It's open source.

You can install Hitch on each Varnish server and accept HTTPS there. The connection between Hitch and Varnish can be done over *Unix Domain Sockets*, which further reduces latency.

Our tests show you can easily process *100 Gbps on a single server* using terminated TLS with Hitch.

### Single tier Varnish or multi-tier Varnish

If your CDN requires a lot of storage, I'd advise you to setup a multi-tier Varnish setup in each geographical location:

- The *edge tier* will be RAM heavy and will cache the *hot content* in memory using the `malloc` stevedore in Varnish
- The *storage tier* will be disk heavy and will cache *long tail content* on disk using the `file` stevedore in Varnish

> Although the `file` stevedore is capable of caching terrabytes of data, it is quite prone to disk fragmentation, which at very large scale will slow you down in the long run.
>
> If you have tiered Varnish servers, you can tune each tier to its needs. Combined, the results will be quite good: although the `file` stevedore has its limitations, it will still be a lot faster than constantly accessing the origin when the cache of the edge servers is full.

### Varnish Software's DIY CDN solution

Varnish Software, the company behind the Varnish Cache project, has done many CDN integration projects for some of the world's biggest web platforms.

*Varnish Cache*, the open source project, is the foundation of these CDN solutions. However, typical CDN clients have some extra requirements, that are not part of the open source solution.

That's why we developed *Varnish Enterprise*, to tackle these limitations.

Have a look at [Varnish Software's DIY CDN solution](https://www.varnish-software.com/solutions/cdn/) to learn more. Please also have a look at [the docs](https://docs.varnish-software.com/varnish-cache-plus/) containing the extra features of the product.

If you want to play around with these features without buying a license up front, you can play around with *Varnish Enterprise* images in the Cloud.

- We have an [AWS image](https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/Varnish-Software-Inc-Varnish-Enterprise-6-Ubuntu/B07L7HVVMF) available on the AWS marketplace.
- We have an [Azure image](https://azuremarketplace.microsoft.com/en-us/marketplace/apps/varnish.varnish-enterprise) available on the Azure marketplace.
- We have a [GCP image](https://console.cloud.google.com/marketplace/details/varnish-public/varnish-enterprise-6-payg-ubuntu) available on the GCP marketplace

Our most significant CDN feature in *Varnish Enterpise* is the [Massive Storage Engine](https://docs.varnish-software.com/varnish-cache-plus/features/mse/). It was specifically built to counter the limitations of the `file` stevedore that is prone to disk fragmentation and non-persistent.

There's a lot of other cool stuff in *Varnish Enterprise* for CDN as well, but you'll find that on the docs pages I referred to.